# Синхронизация локальной и удаленной баз данных

Tags: база-данных, php, синхронизация, mysql

Как лучше реализовать синхронизацию удаленной и локальной баз данных в обе стороны. Чтоб допустим нажал кнопку и они обменялись данными которых нет в той или другой базе. Есть приложение по оценке магазинов и случается так что в магазинах нету интернета. А тут приехала проверка с планшетом оценила магазин по критериям и оценки сохраняются в локальной базе данных на планшете. А когда есть интернет по команде *"Синхронизировать"* обе базы синхронизируются (удаленная-локальная). Помогите хотя бы в какую сторону копать.
Спасибо!

Comment: Обязательно расскажите потом, чем дело закончилось

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как один из вариантов, добавь в каждую таблицу три поля `date_insert`, `date_update`, `date_delete` (например `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL`). В первые два пиши время выполнения одноименных операций `INSERT`, `UPDATE`. Вместо реального удаления строки устанавливай текущее время в поле `date_delete`. Также, нужно где-то фиксировать время последней синхронизации.

В момент синхронизации делай выборку всех записей которые были добавлены, изменены или помечены на удаление с момента последней синхронизации. После удачной синхронизации делай реальное удаление записей помеченных на удаление.

Также нужно определиться с первичными ключами. В системах с распределенным хранением данных первичный ключ должен быть глобально-уникальным. За основу можно взять `UUID()`. Она генерит GUID-идентификатор. Автоинкремент тут не подойдет - базы живут отдельно друг от друга.

Данные синхронизируй с использованием транзакции на принимающей стороне. Учитывая нестабильность соединения транзакция обеспечит целостность выполнения синхронизации.

Answer (score 1):

*Очень интересно, как вы собираетесь устанваливать MySQL на планшет.*

Для решения задач, подобных вашей, в HTML5 сделали [Local storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/). Ваше веб-приложение при этом может работать вообще без сервера, а при подключении к серверу передавать ему накопленные в локальном хранилище данные.

Answer (score 0):

А зачем на планшет устанавливать вообще MySQL? SQLite отлично справляется с задачами. Большинство клиентского ПО пишут с использованием SQLite. В данный момент я сам разрабатываю ПО для магазинов. Синхронизирую базы по методу, который описал KiTE. Сервер - MySQL, клиенты SQLite